# Is there a way to plot the z-Value in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm have got a programme that uses matplotlib and pandas to plot the rolling mean and standard deviation for the price of bitcoin. I'm wondering how I can plot the z values ( the number of standard deviations the price is from the mean).

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

btc_1_day = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Oliver\Desktop\data\data1_btcusdt_1day.csv')

df1_btc = pd.DataFrame(btc_1_day)

df1_btc['SMA_10'] = df1_btc.price_close.rolling(10).mean()
df1_btc['SMSD_10'] = df1_btc.price_close.rolling(10).std()


plt.grid(True)
plt.plot(btc_1_day.price_close)
plt.plot(df1_btc['SMA_10'],label='10 day moving average')
plt.plot(df1_btc['SMSD_10'],label='10 day standard deviation')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have your csv file, I'll show you how I would do this using some random data and a pandas dataframe. You can find the z score using `stats.zscore(df['btc']`, but that would give you numbers on a very different scale from the ones you're trying to plot in your example.

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from scipy import stats

# data
np.random.seed(1234)
numdays=100
df = pd.DataFrame({'btc': (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()})

# moving averages and standard deviations
df['SMA_10'] = df['btc'].rolling(10).mean()
df['SMSD_10+sigma'] = df['btc'].rolling(10).mean()+df['btc'].rolling(10).std()
df['SMSD_10-sigma'] = df['btc'].rolling(10).mean()-df['btc'].rolling(10).std()

# matplotlib
df['ZScore']=stats.zscore(df['btc'])
plt.figure()
df['btc'].plot()
df['ZScore'].plot()
plt.show()
```

In order to illustrate your dataset together with averages and starndard deviations for rolling windows, I'd rather use an approach such as:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from scipy import stats

# data
np.random.seed(1234)
numdays=100
df = pd.DataFrame({'btc': (np.random.randint(low=-20, high=20, size=numdays).cumsum()+100).tolist()})

# moving averages and standard deviations
df['SMA_10'] = df['btc'].rolling(10).mean()
df['SMSD_10+sigma'] = df['btc'].rolling(10).mean()+df['btc'].rolling(10).std()
df['SMSD_10-sigma'] = df['btc'].rolling(10).mean()-df['btc'].rolling(10).std()

# matplotlib
plt.grid(True)
plt.plot( df['btc'])
plt.plot(df['SMA_10'],label='10 day moving average')
plt.plot(df['SMSD_10+sigma'],label='10 day standard deviation',
         color='green',
         linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(df['SMSD_10-sigma'],label='10 day standard deviation',
         color='green',
         linewidth=0.5)
plt.plot(df['btc'], color='blue', linewidth=1.5)
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: i would love to, how do i do that ahah